# TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'cordova.addConstructor')

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, cordova

After installing xcode 6 and iOS 8.1 SDK had such a mistake. Does not work transition between pages in the application, but in Safari it works fine. Console safari gives this error. how to fix it? Im use cordova 4.0.0.

```
cordova.addConstructor(function() {
    if (!window.plugins)
        window.plugins = {};
    window.plugins.pickerView = new PickerView();
});
```

Comment: I do not use Safari regularly but most browsers will tell you the file/line of the file associated with the error. I would get that information and copy/paste the code that the error is pointing out.

Comment: Safari pointing error in this code cordova.addConstructor (top my question)

Comment: Try to comment out the 3 lines in the middle leaving only the first and last and check to see if it errors.

Comment: @Toby, I'm commet this lines, error not fixing

Comment: That tells me that the error is above this code. Verify your syntax and make sure you're not missing any semi colons. Try to verify that Cordova even exists (I do not know what this is but it's possible your browser thinks it does not exist) by using alert(cordova). If it outputs undefined, that's your problem.